# How to store an encoding class object in settings

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, utf-8

I want to store an encoding class object at my WinForms settings, like "Encoding.UTF8".

I know how to workaround this problem by storing a string object, but I don't like solutions like that.

Comment: The Encoding class is abstract, a setting requires a non-abstract class.  So that is not going to fly.  Consider storing the Encoding.CodePage property, recreate it from the setting with Encoding.GetEncoding(value).  It is not 100% kosher but any practical encoding you'd ever want to use does have a valid code page value.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll give it a try, but it sounds very well.

Comment: You can use the name, but in my settings classes I added specific code for making the string "UTF8-NBOM" return a UTF8 encoding initialised to not emit a byte order mark, because having or not having that BOM is very often an issue for communication.